# Error 404 when installing dependencies for firebase functions

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to intall the following

```
npm install --save express body-parser firebase functions-helper
```

but I keep receiving these errors

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/functions-helper - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'functions-helper@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-13T12_53_21_822Z-debug.log
```

So far I tried doing this

```
npm clean cache
```

upgrade node to latest version but I still get the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling your you are trying to install a package that doesn't exist, I cannot find any package called [functions-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=functions-helper), did you mean [firebase-functions-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions-helper)

Answer (score 1):

There is no module called "functions-helper".  If you are writing Cloud Functions using the Firebase tools, you will need to install the module called "firebase-functions", as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).